# postgres functions / extensions not dumped or restored correctly?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

**Update**

Self-answered, see first comment here and my own answer.

**Original question**

I'm setting up a local development postgres db with some sql files, one of them creates a custom function for distance calculations. Extensions "cube" and "earthdistance" are created, the function works as expected.

I'm dumping the local development postgres db, the sql dumps contains the extension creation and the custom function - looks ok.

I'm importing the dump on another test machine without error messages.

But here I'm getting an exception when using the function:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function ll_to_earth(numeric, numeric) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function opengeodb_radius_selection(numeric,numeric,integer,integer) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

The complete SQL code used when setting up the local db:

```
CREATE EXTENSION cube;
CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;

CREATE FUNCTION
    opengeodb_radius_selection(
        baseLatitude numeric(9,6),
        baseLongitude numeric(9,6),
        radius_in_metres integer,
        opengeodb_level integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(
        locid integer,
        name character varying(255),
        distance float8)
AS
$func$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT subQueryAlias.locid, subQueryAlias.name, subQueryAlias.distance
FROM
(
    SELECT *, earth_distance(ll_to_earth(baseLatitude,baseLongitude), ll_to_earth(lat,lon)) as distance
    FROM opengeodb
    GROUP BY opengeodb.locid, opengeodb.lat, opengeodb.lon, opengeodb.name, distance
) subQueryAlias
WHERE plz is not null
AND plz <> ''
AND level = opengeodb_level
AND earth_box(ll_to_earth(lat,lon),radius_in_metres) @> ll_to_earth(baseLatitude,baseLongitude)
AND subQueryAlias.distance <= radius_in_metres
ORDER BY subQueryAlias.distance;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The complete SQL code in the dump:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


--
-- Name: cube; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS cube WITH SCHEMA public;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION cube; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION cube IS 'data type for multidimensional cubes';


--
-- Name: earthdistance; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS earthdistance WITH SCHEMA public;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION earthdistance; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION earthdistance IS 'calculate great-circle distances on the surface of the Earth';


SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

--
-- Name: opengeodb_radius_selection(numeric, numeric, integer, integer); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE FUNCTION opengeodb_radius_selection(baselatitude numeric, baselongitude numeric, radius_in_metres integer, opengeodb_level integer) RETURNS TABLE(locid integer, name character varying, distance double precision)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT subQueryAlias.locid, subQueryAlias.name, subQueryAlias.distance
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, earth_distance(ll_to_earth(baseLatitude,baseLongitude), ll_to_earth(lat,lon)) as distance
        FROM opengeodb
        GROUP BY opengeodb.locid, opengeodb.lat, opengeodb.lon, opengeodb.name, distance
    ) subQueryAlias
    WHERE plz is not null
    AND plz <> ''
    AND level = opengeodb_level
    AND earth_box(ll_to_earth(lat,lon),radius_in_metres) @> ll_to_earth(baseLatitude,baseLongitude)
    AND subQueryAlias.distance <= radius_in_metres
    ORDER BY subQueryAlias.distance;
END
$$;


ALTER FUNCTION public.opengeodb_radius_selection(baselatitude numeric, baselongitude numeric, radius_in_metres integer, opengeodb_level integer) OWNER TO postgres;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

...(followed by table creation and so on)
```

Is this my fault or erroneous behaviour?

Comment: Note: I'll have a look at this: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/45378976.5090208%40presinet.com (development environment is win10, other test system is Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 - maybe there are just missing pg packages on the debian system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-Answering (see first question comment)

On the debian system 9.4.10 was installed, and there is no postgresql-contrib for 9.4.10 for debian (but in my development windows postgres package, also 9.4.10)

We've updated the debian system to 9.4.12 and now contrib is included, the function works fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`ll_to_earth` is defined as taking arguments `(float8, float8)`, but you are passing `numeric, numeric`.  So you will need to add some casts to your function.

It's not clear why it worked previously.  Perhaps you were upgrading from an older version?

Comment: No, it has been an installation problem. Now it's pg 9.4.12 on the debian system and extensions and my function work fine.